# Checkboxes behave like Radiobutton

Tags: html, angularjs, checkbox, radio-button

I have got 4 checkboxes ad they should act like checkboxes, but they don't.
I just can select one. Can somebody please help me with my problem?

My second question is, is it possible that they are all selected from the beginning?

Thanks!

I think i descriped my question wrong, I can click for example two checkboxes, but then nothing is shown.

Eg.: if i click green and red, then both colors should be shown.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group"> 
    <input type="checkbox" id="stat1" ng-true-value="'black'" ng-model="statusblack"/>&nbsp;
    <label for="stat1">black</label><br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="stat2" ng-true-value="'red'" ng-model="statusred"/>&nbsp;
    <label for="stat2">red</label><br />                               
    <input type="checkbox" id="stat3" ng-true-value="'yellow'" ng-model="statusyellow"/>&nbsp;
    <label for="stat3">yellowt</label><br />   
    <input type="checkbox" id="stat4" ng-true-value="'green'" ng-model="statusgreen"/>&nbsp;
    <label for="stat4">green</label><br />                     
</div>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th>Info</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="co in $ctrl.colors | filter:statusred | filter:statusblack | filter:statusgreen | filter:statusyellow">
            <td>{{ co.no }}</td>
            <td>{{ co.color }}</td>
            <td>{{ co.info }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: I am able to select any checkbox. for second question, if you want to set them selected add **checked** attribute of each checkbox like `<input type="checkbox" id="stat1" ng-true-value="'black'" ng-model="statusblack" checked />`

Answer (score 1):

Add checked in input tag

```html
<div class="form-group"> 
    <input type="checkbox" id="stat1" ng-true-value="'black'" ng-model="statusblack"/>&nbsp;
    <label for="stat1">black</label><br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="stat2" ng-true-value="'red'" ng-model="statusred"/>&nbsp;
    <label for="stat2">red</label><br />                               
    <input type="checkbox" id="stat3" ng-true-value="'yellow'" ng-model="statusyellow"/>&nbsp;
    <label for="stat3">yellowt</label><br />   
    <input type="checkbox" id="stat4" ng-true-value="'green'" ng-model="statusgreen" checked/>&nbsp;
    <label for="stat4">green</label><br />                     
</div>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th>Info</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="co in $ctrl.colors | filter:statusred | filter:statusblack | filter:statusgreen | filter:statusyellow">
            <td>{{ co.no }}</td>
            <td>{{ co.color }}</td>
            <td>{{ co.info }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the code sample you provided,  they are acting like check boxes. 
And regarding the second question you can use `ng-checked="true"` to check the checkbox 
initially

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <div class="form-group"> 
    <input type="checkbox" id="stat1" ng-true-value="'black'"  ng-model="statusblack" ng-checked="true"/>&nbsp;
    <label for="stat1">black</label><br /> 
    <input type="checkbox" id="stat2" ng-true-value="'red'" ng-model="statusred" ng-checked="true"/>&nbsp;
    <label for="stat2">red</label><br />                               
    <input type="checkbox" id="stat3" ng-true-value="'yellow'" ng-model="statusyellow" ng-checked="true"/>&nbsp;
    <label for="stat3">yellowt</label><br />   
    <input type="checkbox" id="stat4" ng-true-value="'green'" ng-model="statusgreen" ng-checked="true"/>&nbsp;
    <label for="stat4">green</label><br />                     
</div>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th>Info</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
        <tr ng-repeat="co in $ctrl.colors | filter:statusred | filter:statusblack | filter:statusgreen | filter:statusyellow">
            <td>{{ co.no }}</td>
            <td>{{ co.color }}</td>
            <td>{{ co.info }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All checkbox can be selected.

Second question:

If you want to make it selected from the start of page, just put *checked="true"*

example:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="stat1" ng-true-value="'black'" checked="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the code does work.

In regards to having it checked by default you need to add `checked` at the end of the  input tag.

E.g.
`<input type="checkbox" id="stat1" ng-true-value="'black'" ng-model="statusblack" checked/>`

Refer to [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp) for more info.